# Gray image from green channel

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

I was reading an article and they work on the gray image from green channel. They work with retina images and detect blood vessels on it.

My questions are that:

What does 'gray image from green channel' mean?

How can I get this gray image from green channel?

What is the difference between the gray image which is result of this matlab code `I = rgb2gray(RGB)` and gray image from green channel?

Thank you.

Comment: The "grey image from the green channel" is probably just the green channel information represented as levels of grey. It would be: `I = RGB(:,:,2)` (that is, select the second channelm which is the green channel). So it represents changes in the green component. On the other hand, `I = rgb2gray(RGB)` represents changes in (a weighted sum of) all colors

Comment: Try it! Load an RGB image and do I = rgb2gray(RGB) adn as Luis suggested, I = RGB(:,:,2), and then check the results!

Comment: @LuisMendo You are right. I got answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can do it with ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux/Unix boxes and available for free for Windows and OSX like this:

Starting with this image:

[image]

```
convert plant.jpg -separate -delete 0,2 out.jpg
```

That separates the image into Red, Green and Blue channels, then deletes the Red and Blue channels leaving just the Green channel which then becomes a monochromatic (grey) representation of the amount of green in each pixel - so the green of the plant shows up the brightest/lightest.

[image]